# How to send document file in JSQMessageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, io, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to send document files in `JSQMessageViewController` for an application I am building. How to do that?

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this? I was wondering the same thing

Comment: Hi @Jaqueline sorry for replying late, i was able to extend JSQMessagecontroller to send documents but the changes are in my local machine, will make a github repo of that and share the link by tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @Zoom have you put it together yet? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jaqueline I’m so sorry it totally slipped from my mind but I’ll do it by today positively.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Zoom have you implement sending document ?